# Backbone is unable to find the dynamic div created by template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

- Fetch collection  (OK)
- Index Render View (OK)
- Render view for indiviual item in collection (NOT OK)

  ```
  class MyApp.Routers.ProjectsRouter extends Backbone.Router

    initialize: ->
      @projects = new MyApp.Collections.ProjectsCollection()

    routes:
      "projects" : "projects"

    projects: ->
      @projects.fetch().done =>
        @view = new MyApp.Views.Projects.IndexView(collection: @projects)
        $("#projects").html(@view.render().el)

  class MyApp.Views.Projects.IndexView extends Backbone.View
    template: JST["backbone/templates/projects/index"]

    addAll: =>
      @collection.each(@addOne)

    addOne: (project) =>
      view = new MyApp.Views.Projects.ProjectView({ model: project })
      **$(".row-fluid").append(view.render().el)**

    render: =>
      @$el.html(@template('<div class="row-fluid"></div>'))
      @addAll()
      this

  class MyApp.Views.Projects.ProjectView extends Backbone.View
    template: JST["backbone/templates/projects/project"]

    render: ->
      @$el.append(@template())
      this
  ```

".row-fluid" is not founded, i have debugged it using firebug. Somebody please help me i have been banging my head from last 5 6 hours.

Thanks

Comment: Silly question, but `.row-fluid` is found in the template? Care to show the template code?

Comment: Could you prepare some simple jsFiddle? $(".row-fluid") is global selector so you don't have such element in your DOM tree.

Comment: Missing braces passing in collection -> `@view = new MyApp.Views.Projects.IndexView({collection: @projects})`

Comment: @msvalkon added template code @$el.html(@template('<div class="row-fluid"></div>'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyApp.Routers.ProjectsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  projects: ->
    @projects.fetch().done =>
      @view = new MyApp.Views.Projects.IndexView(collection: @projects)
      $("#projects").html(@view.render().el)
      @view.addAll()

class MyApp.Views.Projects.IndexView extends Backbone.View
  render: =>
    @$el.html(@template('<div class="row-fluid"></div>'))
    this
```